# C# How to delete items in the listbox(loaded from textfile)

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I delete selected item from the listbox. The content of the listbox is from a text File and I use StreamReader to read all content in the textfile and display in the listbox. And If i delete it, will it update the textfile ?

Populate listbox

```
        public void Outbound_load()
    {
        Listbox1.Items.Clear();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\Outbound.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
            // the file is reached. 
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Listbox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that you are using to populate the listbox, Changes made in the listbox items won't alter the text file content until you wrote code for that

Comment: How are you doing your databinding ?

Comment: "And If i delete it, will it update the textfile?" Of course not, you have to write the file. How about any response to the answers to your previous question?

Comment: I updated the codes. Thats how I populate the listbox

Comment: I dont think I have databinding

Comment: Backup your file and try it. 

Comment: Keep it simple. Use `File.ReadAllLines` (as already suggested) and `File.WriteAllLines`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
public void Save(string filePath)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, listBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found the solution

```
     public void Del_in()
    {

        if (Listbox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            Listbox2.Items.RemoveAt(Listbox2.SelectedIndex);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                    foreach (string item in Listbox2.Items)
                        tw.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's a bad solution. Why don't you use bindings?